# xpath locators c# proper technique of finding

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I'm trying to master my xPath findings but I'm facing a problem. My goal is to get checkbox from the table. Could you please give me any advices how locator should always be set?

Let's imagine that my goal is the **input** pointing on **checkbox** which needs to be clicked.

Firstly I tried in really simple way:

```
By.XPath("//input[@type = 'checkbox'][1]")
```

I've got two checkboxes so I'm pointing to get the first one. Result - Fail.

Next:

```
By.XPath("//div[@class = 'receipt-grid-container h-90']//tbody/tr[1]/td[5]/input");
```

I'm starting from the main class and going "down", through tbody and table elements. As my checkbox is located inside the 5th column I've tried to find it by ending it with /input. Result - Fail also.

And the final approach, I supposed it could be done just by "going down" so:

```
By.XPath("//div[@class = 'receipt-grid-container h-90']//tbody/tr[1]/td[5]/div/input");
```

However, I failed also. Can anyone advice me how we can find it? Also, when we're searching for the xpath, is there a need starting "from the top to the bottom" technique like I'm doing above? Or we can start in different way using e.g xPath Axes

```html
<div class="receipt-grid-container h-90">
   <div style="height: auto; overflow: auto;">
      <div>
         <table style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0px; table-layout: fixed; font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;">
            <thead style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(224, 224, 224);">
               <tr style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(224, 224, 224); color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87); height: 48px;">
                  <th width="35%" style="font-weight: normal; font-size: 12px; padding-left: 24px; padding-right: 24px; height: 56px; text-align: left; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis; color: rgb(158, 158, 158); position: relative; background-color: inherit;">
                     <!-- react-text: 1986 -->Name<!-- /react-text -->
                  </th>
                  <th width="15%" style="font-weight: normal; font-size: 12px; padding-left: 24px; padding-right: 24px; height: 56px; text-align: left; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis; color: rgb(158, 158, 158); position: relative; background-color: inherit;">
                     <!-- react-text: 1988 -->Quantity<!-- /react-text -->
                  </th>
                  <th width="20%" style="font-weight: normal; font-size: 12px; padding-left: 24px; padding-right: 24px; height: 56px; text-align: left; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis; color: rgb(158, 158, 158); position: relative; background-color: inherit;">
                     <!-- react-text: 1990 -->EUR<!-- /react-text -->
                  </th>
                  <th width="15%" style="font-weight: normal; font-size: 12px; padding-left: 24px; padding-right: 24px; height: 56px; text-align: left; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis; color: rgb(158, 158, 158); position: relative; background-color: inherit;">
                     <!-- react-text: 1992 -->Refunded<!-- /react-text -->
                  </th>
                  <th width="15%" style="font-weight: normal; font-size: 12px; padding-left: 24px; padding-right: 24px; height: 56px; text-align: left; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis; color: rgb(158, 158, 158); position: relative; background-color: inherit;">
                     <!-- react-text: 1994 -->Refund<!-- /react-text -->
                  </th>
               </tr>
            </thead>
         </table>
      </div>
      <div style="height: inherit; overflow: hidden auto;">
         <table style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0px; table-layout: fixed; font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;">
            <tbody>
               <tr style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(224, 224, 224); color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87); height: 48px;">
                  <td width="35%" style="padding-left: 24px; padding-right: 24px; height: 48px; text-align: left; font-size: 13px; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis; background-color: inherit;">Coca-Cola 0,5 l</td>
                  <td width="15%" style="padding-left: 24px; padding-right: 24px; height: 48px; text-align: left; font-size: 13px; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis; background-color: inherit;">1 pcs</td>
                  <td width="20%" style="padding-left: 24px; padding-right: 24px; height: 48px; text-align: left; font-size: 13px; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis; background-color: inherit;">3.00</td>
                  <td width="15%" style="padding-left: 24px; padding-right: 24px; height: 48px; text-align: left; font-size: 13px; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis; background-color: inherit;">0</td>
                  <td width="15%" style="padding-left: 24px; padding-right: 24px; height: 48px; text-align: left; font-size: 13px; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis; background-color: inherit;">
                     <div style="cursor: pointer; position: relative; overflow: visible; display: table; height: auto; width: 100%;">
                        <!-- react-empty: 2005 --><input type="checkbox" value="on" style="position: absolute; cursor: inherit; pointer-events: all; opacity: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: 2; left: 0px; box-sizing: border-box; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">
                        <div style="display: flex; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
                           <div style="transition: all 450ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 0ms; float: left; position: relative; display: block; flex-shrink: 0; width: 24px; margin-right: 16px; margin-left: 0px; height: 24px;">
                              <div>
                                 <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" style="display: inline-block; color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87); fill: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87); height: 24px; width: 24px; user-select: none; transition: opacity 1000ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 200ms; position: absolute; opacity: 1;">
                                    <path d="M19 5v14H5V5h14m0-2H5c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2v14c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h14c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V5c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2z"></path>
                                 </svg>
                                 <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" style="display: inline-block; color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87); fill: rgb(0, 188, 212); height: 24px; width: 24px; user-select: none; transition: opacity 450ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 0ms, transform 0ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 450ms; position: absolute; opacity: 0; transform: scale(0);">
                                    <path d="M19 3H5c-1.11 0-2 .9-2 2v14c0 1.1.89 2 2 2h14c1.11 0 2-.9 2-2V5c0-1.1-.89-2-2-2zm-9 14l-5-5 1.41-1.41L10 14.17l7.59-7.59L19 8l-9 9z"></path>
                                 </svg>
                              </div>
                              <div></div>
                              <div style="position: absolute; height: 100%; width: 100%; top: 0px; left: 0px;"></div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </td>
               </tr>
               <tr style="color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87); height: 48px;">
                  <td width="35%" style="padding-left: 24px; padding-right: 24px; height: 48px; text-align: left; font-size: 13px; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis; background-color: inherit;">Fanta Zero 0,5 l</td>
                  <td width="15%" style="padding-left: 24px; padding-right: 24px; height: 48px; text-align: left; font-size: 13px; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis; background-color: inherit;">1 pcs</td>
                  <td width="20%" style="padding-left: 24px; padding-right: 24px; height: 48px; text-align: left; font-size: 13px; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis; background-color: inherit;">3.00</td>
                  <td width="15%" style="padding-left: 24px; padding-right: 24px; height: 48px; text-align: left; font-size: 13px; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis; background-color: inherit;">0</td>
                  <td width="15%" style="padding-left: 24px; padding-right: 24px; height: 48px; text-align: left; font-size: 13px; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis; background-color: inherit;">
                     <div style="cursor: pointer; position: relative; overflow: visible; display: table; height: auto; width: 100%;">
                        <!-- react-empty: 2023 --><input type="checkbox" value="on" style="position: absolute; cursor: inherit; pointer-events: all; opacity: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: 2; left: 0px; box-sizing: border-box; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">
                        <div style="display: flex; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
                           <div style="transition: all 450ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 0ms; float: left; position: relative; display: block; flex-shrink: 0; width: 24px; margin-right: 16px; margin-left: 0px; height: 24px;">
                              <div>
                                 <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" style="display: inline-block; color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87); fill: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87); height: 24px; width: 24px; user-select: none; transition: opacity 1000ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 200ms; position: absolute; opacity: 1;">
                                    <path d="M19 5v14H5V5h14m0-2H5c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2v14c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h14c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V5c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2z"></path>
                                 </svg>
                                 <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" style="display: inline-block; color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87); fill: rgb(0, 188, 212); height: 24px; width: 24px; user-select: none; transition: opacity 450ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 0ms, transform 0ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 450ms; position: absolute; opacity: 0; transform: scale(0);">
                                    <path d="M19 3H5c-1.11 0-2 .9-2 2v14c0 1.1.89 2 2 2h14c1.11 0 2-.9 2-2V5c0-1.1-.89-2-2-2zm-9 14l-5-5 1.41-1.41L10 14.17l7.59-7.59L19 8l-9 9z"></path>
                                 </svg>
                              </div>
                              <div></div>
                              <div style="position: absolute; height: 100%; width: 100%; top: 0px; left: 0px;"></div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </td>
               </tr>
            </tbody>
         </table>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the *HTML* you have shared your *usecase* might be either to click the *checkbox* for the item **Coca-Cola** or the *checkbox* for the item **Fanta Zero**. So to click the respective *checkbox* you can create a function as follows:

```
public void click_checkbox(string softdrink)
{
    driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[contains(@class,'receipt-grid-container')]//table/tbody//td[contains(.,'" + softdrink + "')]//following::input[1]")).Click();
}
```

Now you can call the function `click_checkbox()` with the required item which ever you want to click as follows:

```
click_checkbox("Coca-Cola")
//or
click_checkbox("Fanta Zero")
```

Comment: Just amazing solution, works like crazy. Thanks Debanjan!

Comment: Debanjan could you please tell me why did you use "." and "," in second "contains" (td)? td[contains(.,'" + softdrink + "')]

Comment: Great question. `contains(.,'" + softdrink + "')` is the cleaner and broader way of passing a variable text as in `text()='character_sequence'`

Answer (score 1):

Try using this as your xpath:

```
By.XPath("(//input[@type = 'checkbox'])[1]")
```

Generally, try selecting the elements by `id` (it *should* be unique, but it isn't always), then `name`, and after that I would keep them as simple as possible, without using too many numbered elements (e.g. `//div[13]/span[9]//td/td[4]/div`).

Comment: Tried exactly as you advised me but unfortunately it does not work :(